# windows 10 hosts file entries been commented out

Tags: windows-10, hosts, hosts-file, bitdefender

Windows 10 is commenting out my hosts file entries. This happens periodically so every 1 hour.

Although I manage to save the changes but they will be commented out after around 1 hour.

I never experienced such thing on any Windows version before so maybe there is something I need to do in Windows 10 to prevent this from happening.

I have Bitdefender Total Security 2016 installed.

Comment: Have you checked for a a virus/malware/...?

Comment: I have bitdefender installed. I am not sure if bitdefender would comment out my hosts file

Comment: According to [BitDefender 2016 keeps adding a # to entries in the hosts file](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3lzlxs/bitdefender_2016_keeps_adding_a_to_entries_in_the/) it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sul,

Cause: Bitdefender Total Security 2016 is causing this problem

Fix: Right click on hosts file, properties, security, give only read access to "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" user/group.

Reference: http://www.bitdefender.com/security/hosts-file-hijacking-becomes-impossible-in-windows-8.html

Comment: "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" has read and read & execute permission. I am unable to change them as they are grayed out. I can deny read & execute but this in turn will deny ready

Comment: Sul, On the top right, hit Human icon, hit "General Settings", then "Advanced", takeoff selected flag on "Scan host files"

Comment: This one is no longer effective.

Comment: This will block Bitdefender from commenting out intentional entries.  But will this block unintentional entries?

Is this a bit like solving a jammed door, by not closing it?

Answer (score 39):

To prevent the hosts entries from being commented out by Bitdefender 2016 do the following:

In the main Bitdefender interface click on the human icon (from the upper right corner) and choose `General Settings` > `Advanced tab` > `"Scan hosts file"` button.

[image: Screenshot of this option]

Comment: Could you possibly include a screenshot of this option?

Comment: True, but it leaves your hosts file vulnerable. So be cautions about this workaround. (Webroot solves this by locking the hosts file. You have to unlock it before every change you need to make. Cumbersome, but more secure.)

Comment: This option has been moved in recent versions to Protection > Vulnerability > Settings.